# XGBoost for multiclassification and imbalanced data

Tags: python, xgboost, multiclass-classification, imbalanced-data, xgbclassifier

I am dealing with a classification problem with 3 classes [0,1,2], and imbalanced class distribution as shown below.

[image]

I want to apply **XGBClassifier** (in Python) to this classification problem, but the model does not respond to `class_weight` adjustments and skews towards the majority class 0, and ignores the minority classes 1,2. Which hyperparameters other than `class_weight` can help me?

I tried 1) computing class weights using sklearn `compute_class_weight`; 2) setting weights according to the relative frequency of the classes; 3) and also manually adjusting classes with extreme values to see if any change happens at all, such as `{0:0.5,1:100,2:200}`. But in any case, it does not help the classifier to take the minority classes into account.

**Observations:**

- I can handle the problem in the *binary case*: If I make the problem a binary classification by identifying classes [1,2], then I can get the classifier work properly by adjusting `scale_pos_weight` (even in this case `class_weight` alone does not help).
  But `scale_pos_weight`, as far as I know, works for binary classification. Is there an analogue of this parameter for the multi-classification problems?
- Using `RandomForestClassifier` instead of `XGBClassifier`, I can handle the problem by setting `class_weight='balanced_subsample'` and tunning `max_leaf_nodes`. But, for some reason, this approach does not work for XGBClassifier.

**Remark:** I know about balancing techniques, such as over/undersampling, or SMOTE. But I want to avoid them as much as possible, and prefer a solutions using hyperparameter tunning of the model if possible.
My observation above shows that this can work for the binary case.

Comment: First, try to balance data with "Oversampling and Undersampling" techniques, then you can classification with normal distribution on balanced data.

Comment: @PooyaChavoshi Thanks for the comment. I should have added that I prefer to avoid using over/undersampling techniques and approaches like SMOTE as much as possible. I've tried them however

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**`sample_weight`** parameter is useful for handling imbalanced data while using `XGBoost` for training the data. You can compute sample weights by using `compute_sample_weight()` of `sklearn` library.

This code should work for multiclass data:

```py
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_sample_weight
sample_weights = compute_sample_weight(
    class_weight='balanced',
    y=train_df['class'] #provide your own target name
)

xgb_classifier.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weights)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It did work!
The key point I was missing was that the parameter `sample_weight` should be passed while fitting.

Comment: What's the difference between scale_pos_weight and sample_weight?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sample_weight as @Prakash Dahal suggested, but compute your own weights. I found that different weights made a dramatic difference (I have 12 classes and very imbalanced data).
If you compute your own weights, you need to assign the relevant weight to each entry and pass the param to the classifier in the same way:
xgb_class.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight=weights)